# Dialogflow message with audio input (chat bot Dialogflow cx)

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I have created an agent by DialogFlow Cx and I need do a web demo. I'm trying create this page using Dialog Flow message:

```
<DOCKTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> PocJbsEngineering </title>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/dialogflow-console/fast/messenger-cx/bootstrap.js?v=1"></script>
    <df-messenger df-cx="true" location="us-east1" chat-title="JBS" agent-id="bfb3f030-9d41-4160-b13c-90de6f3b8c1d"
        language-code="pt-br" request.inputAudio = "audio"></df-messenger>
       
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

but, the chat message doesnt have the voice input:

[chat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMOCr.png)

How can I put a voice input on Dialogflow message? some suggestion to do this agent Dialogflow Cx with audio input?

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately as you pointed out the embedded version doesn't have audio as an input.

If you want to use the embedded chat then you'd need to record your voice and convert it to text using speech to text.

If you wanted to create your own UI then you should use Dialogflow CX v1beta2 and the type InputAudioConfig. You'd record your voice and use the InputAudioConfig to pass into the detect intent call. Similar to the link below just with Dialogflow CX instead of ES

https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/how/detect-intent-audio

Comment: Do you know if this still the case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77504988/how-to-enable-microphone-for-published-dialogflow-web-agent-despite-being-avail.  Thank you!