# How to enable microphone for published Dialogflow web agent? despite being available when testing in simulator

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, dialogflow-cx

I am trying to publish a Dialogflow CX agent to the web with the option that users can use the audio to ask questions (speech to text).
When I test it in the simulator, it's working fine, while the deployed version doesn't have it (I'm using Google Chrome if that helps).
Here's the embedding code as well as screenshots from simulator and deployed version

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/dialogflow-console/fast/df-messenger/prod/v1/df-messenger.js"></script>
<df-messenger
  location=""
  project-id=""
  agent-id=""
  language-code="en">
  <df-messenger-chat-bubble
   chat-title="">
  </df-messenger-chat-bubble>
</df-messenger>
<style>
  df-messenger {
    z-index: 999;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 16px;
    right: 16px;
  }
</style>
```

Here's a screenshot from the simulator (microphone option is visible AND working)
[image]

And here's the one for the deployed agent where the microphone is missing
[image]